# How to pass input parameters to controller actions in php mvc with $.get() or $.post() methods ajax jquery?

Tags: php, ajax

How to pass input parameters to controller actions in php mvc with `$.get()` or `$.post()` methods ajax jquery?

In my php code how can I send `$username` parameter to checkUserName action?
Can I send this parameter as option data parameter in `$.get()` or `$.pos()` ajax?

```
//my class. this class is for users
class User extends Controller
{    
    // construct class
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    // my action. this actin check username in database
    public function checkUserName($username)
    {
      // enter code here
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

with post method

```
function get_username() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'controller/method',
        type: "post",
        data: {
            'username': username,
        },
        success: function(data) {
        },
    });
}


<?php public function checkUserName()
            {
              $username = $_POST['username'];
                  or
              $username = $_GET['username'];
            }
```

change the type to `GET` for get method

Comment: thanks for your answer. but return this warning and Notice: <b>Warning</b>:  Missing argument 1 for User::checkUserName(), called in ...  <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: username in ...